# ListViewItem's Image always in front of the Texts

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I configured my TListView ItemAppearance like this:`DynamicAppearance`. Then I opened the `Toggle Design Mode` and configured all the text/images exactly like I want, the problem is: I Need a background image in my listView item, but the image in this case always keep on front of my texts. How can I send my image to back (I alredy used the command `Send to Back` in my image and `Bring to Front` in my texts, but nothing seems to work).

A image to ilustrate:

[image]

I want send the Image 8 to back, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the objects property change the order of your image (arrow up). It will display the differences only at runtime or if you force it refresh like alt+F12.

[image: Image in front of Text]

[image]